# emmeans - joint effects of interaction terms

Tags: interaction, contrasts, ratio, marginal-effect

I would like to see the joint effects of an interaction term. I tried joint_tests() but it gives f ratios. However, I would prefer Incidence Rate Ratios (IRR) because the rest of my results section uses those. My model is a GLMM with Poisson distribution. Any ideas?

I also tried the following but the outcome remains the same:

```
EMM <- emmeans(model1, ~ A | B) 
PRS <- contrast(EMM, "revpairwise", interaction = "consec")  
summary(PRS)
summary(PRS, type = "response", infer = c(TRUE, TRUE))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is IRR *really* interval rate ratios, or do you mean *incidence* rate ratios? I'm well familiar with Poisson models for estimating the latter, but have never heard of the former

Comment: You can use, say, `contrast(emm, interaction = "consec")` to obtain comparisons of comparisons at consecutive levels. See the vignette on interactions.

Comment: @RussLenth Hi, I've tried that but my outcome is the same, any advice?
I quickly added your suggestion in the question to show what I did.

Comment: @AdamO Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thee are two things wrong. One, you asked for both regular contrasts and interaction contrasts. So decide which (interaction I think, but I'm never sure I understand what you want). Second, if you do want interaction contrasts, your EMM has B as a by variable, so A is out there by itself with nothing to interact with. Try contrast(EMM, interaction = "consec", by = NULL). And also think about this and do your best to understand why.

Comment: @RussLenth I see what you mean, makes sense. Although you never know what I want, you find the right solution. Thank you for that. Again, your answer has helped me. I hope you know how valuable your advice is to lost students.